# Junit : status expected <200> but it was <400>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit4

I am trying to write test case for `post` request on controller level. when I am running through postman I am getting `200 0k`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @Autowired
    HelloService helloService;  

    @PostMapping("/post")
    public Hello helloPost(@RequestBody Hello hello) {
        return hello;       
    }
}

class Hello {
    private String title;   
    private String value; 

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Hello(String title, String value) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Hello() {
        super();
    }           
}
```

**Test case**

```
@Test
public void helloPost() throws Exception {

    String json = "{\n" +
                  " \"title\":\"Greetting\", \n" + 
                  " \"value\":\"Hello world\",\n" + 
                  "}";

    mockMvc.perform(post("/hello/post")
                     .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                     .content(json))
                     .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the json like below:-

```
String json = "{\"title\":\"Greetting\",\"value\":\"Hello world\"}";
```

Comment: it could be related to multiple things like the new line characters and spaces and an extra comma in the last